# Intergrating background images on PHPRad

Tags: javascript, php, html5-canvas

Good Day Everyone, I have a PHPrad project I am working on, I am fairly new to PHPRad so I am struggling a bit with my html canvas tag.

**Problem**

I am using custom view option to add ny script tag and it does not seem to work. I am also using a custom HTML Page. I want to add an html 5 canvas tag and set its background to an image I uploaded online, When I do so, nothing shows up and despite trying to prevent the drawing and erasing button from automatically submitting the form when clicked, the buttons do submit the form

Here is the Code.

```js
alert('testing if the script is well connected')

const canvas = document.getElementById("corolla-canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

const img = new Image();
img.src = "https://i.ibb.co/QF5k508/Removal-69.png";
img.onload = function () {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
};

let isDrawing = false;
let isErasing = false;

const drawButton = document.getElementById("corollax-draw");
const removeButton = document.getElementById("corollax-remove");

drawButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  removeButton.disabled = false;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startDrawing);
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", endDrawing);
});

removeButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  drawButton.disabled = false;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startErasing);
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", erase);
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", endErasing);
});

function startDrawing(e) {
  isDrawing = true;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
}

function draw(e) {
  if (isDrawing) {
    ctx.lineTo(e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

function endDrawing(e) {
  isDrawing = false;
}

function startErasing(e) {
  isErasing = true;
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
}

function erase(e) {
  if (isErasing) {
    ctx.lineTo(e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft, e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

function endErasing(e) {
  isErasing = false;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";
}

drawButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  removeButton.disabled = false;
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startDrawing);
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", endDrawing);
});

removeButton.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  drawButton.disabled = false;
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-out";
  canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startErasing);
  canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", erase);
  canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", endErasing);
});
```

```html
<div class="canvases">
                <!-- Corolla Canvas -->
                <div class="corolla-canvas">
                  <input type="hidden" name="corolla_data" value="" />
                  <div class="buttons-container">
                    <button id="corollax-draw" class="form-button">
                      Free Drawing
                    </button>
                    <button id="corollax-remove" disabled="disabled">Remove</button>
                  </div>
                  <canvas
                    id="corolla-canvas"
                    width="650px"
                    height="330px"
                    name="corolla_data"
                  ></canvas>
                </div>
                  </canvas>
                </div>
```

Here are my image of how it all looks when I preview it.. I want the image to show and the draw and remove buttons to function acordingly instead of submitting the form:

Comment: Where are your images ?

Comment: I put my images online sir